# cloudfoundry rails 3.2.3 ruby 1.9 deploy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud-foundry

I am new to cloudfoundry and rails, I am trying to deploy a new application to cloudfoundry, and I got this error:

```
====> /logs/migration.log <====

←[31mYou have requested:
  mysql2 ~> 0.3.11

The bundle currently has mysql2 locked at 0.3.11.
Try running `bundle update mysql2`←[0m
```

I downloaded a few rails samples from here:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples 
with the same results.

I already tried 'bundle update mysql2'

If I push a simple ruby app that requires the gem mysql2 it works fine.

I am using  windows 7 x64.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Not a bad idea to review http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/ruby/ruby-cf.html, which describes items that should be in your Gemfile. Commands that are easily forgotten are "bundle package", and "rake assets:precompile". I also suggest "vmc push --runtime ruby19..."

Comment: I tried specifying the runtime without success, I am following this guide: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/ruby/rails-3-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with deploying ruby apps bundled on Windows to CloudFoundry.com (which is Linux-based). The workaround is to modify your Gemfile.lock and delete occurrences of the string `-x86-mingw32`. Then re-push the app to Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm that you have run;

```
bundle update
bundle package
```

before using VMC to push the application.

Comment: Hi, yes, I am doing that, I am following this guide(for rails 3.1): http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/ruby/rails-3-1.html, plus the "bundle update"